# BehaviorRelay not updating the view in Collection view on call. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, rx-swift

say I have a `UIViewController` in which I have 2 other view which are actually `UICollectionViews` embedded in two different container views. Say CV1 = `class_Numbers` and CV2 = `students_Data`. Now I want to perform an action on `students_Data` and change Student class data on `itemSelected` click from the class_Numbers. `BehaviorRelay` to update on runtime. And I have bind them in `MainViewController`. Have a look on code for better understanding.

**student_data CV Class**

```
dataSource.configureCell = { (ds, cv, ip, item) in
            let cell = cv.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "studentCV", for: ip) as! StudentCVCell
            cell.viewModel = item
            classIdd = item.classId
            return cell
        }
            studentCells
                .asObservable()
                .debug("STudent View: ")
                .map({ [SectionViewModel(header: "", items: $0.filter({$0.pickupStatus == 2}) ), SectionViewModel(header: "", items: $0.filter({$0.pickupStatus == 3}) )] })
                .bind(to: studentsView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource))
                .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

**class_number CollectionView**

```
  let studentCells = BehaviorRelay<[StudentModel]>(value: [])
    let classCells = BehaviorRelay<[ClassModel]>(value: [])
func setupBind{
// other functions
        // item selection with model details.
Observable
            .zip(
                classTab
                    .rx
                    .itemSelected,
                classTab
                    .rx
                    .modelSelected(ClassModel.self))
            .bind { [weak self] indexPath, model in
                AppFunctions.setSelectedTab(value: indexPath.row)
                self!.tab.onNext(self!.tabStatus(index: indexPath.row))
                self!.studentCells.accept(Array(Database.singleton.fetchStudents(byCLassId: model.classId))) // here I am trying to update view by passing value to the observable. 
            }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

**StudentViewModel**

```
 let studentCells = BehaviorRelay<[StudentModel]>(value: [])
    let classCells = BehaviorRelay<[ClassModel]>(value: [])
    var studentCell : Observable<[StudentModel]> {
        return studentCells.asObservable()
    }
    var classCell : Observable<[ClassModel]> {
        return classCells.asObservable()
    }
 func getStudentsData(id: Int) { // this function is being called on the mainViewController which have both collection views.
        let studentsData = Database.singleton.fetchStudents(byCLassId: id)
        self.notificationToken = studentsData.observe{[weak self] change in
            switch change {
            case .initial(_):
                self!.studentCells.accept(Array(studentsData))
                self!.classCells.accept(Array(Database.singleton.fetchClass()))
                break
            case .update(_, _, _, _):
                self!.studentCells.accept(Array(studentsData))
                self!.classCells.accept(Array(Database.singleton.fetchClass()))
                break
            case .error(let error):
                print(error)
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

**MainViewController**

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            getAssignedClassData(classId: id)
                self!.viewModel.getStudentsData(id: id)
    }
    func getAssignedClassData(classId: Int) {
        return APIService.singelton
            .getClassById(classId: classId)
            .subscribe({ [weak self] _ in
                // something happening
            })
            .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
    }
 func bindViewModel() {
        viewModel
            .studentCell
            .asObservable()
            .debug("BIND: ")
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            .bind(to: studentsViewController.studentCells)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

            viewModel
            .classCell
            .asObservable()
            .debug("CELL BIND: ")
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            .bind(to: classViewController.classCells)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
```

Comment: What is the question? Why are there duplicate studentCells and classCells? Why is your CollectionView holding a model data? It's really hard to read your code.

Comment: my question is, how can I update data in `studentCells` to update views from another `UiCollectionView` on cell tap. And duplication in **StudentViewModel** is because I want to update it every time there is been a change in Database.

Comment: is there something you have for me?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your code

Comment: What else you want to understand? I can provide.